# How to right and left align every alternate list item in html and css along with the bullets

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to right align alternate list elements and keep the other left making it a ZIG-ZAG list
Something like..
Item1
                                                                    Item2
Item3 
                                                                    Item4

I was able to achieve this but without the bullets the bullets of right were still in the left so how do i do that with the bullets......

```
ul{
list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 0;
```

}

```
ul li {
    margin: 25px 0;
    padding-left: 45px;
}
ul li.odd {
    float:right;
}
    ul li.even {
        position:relative;
    }



 <ul>
   <li class="odd">
      Item1  
    </li>

     <li class="even">
        Item2
    </li>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    ul li {
        margin: 25px 0;
        padding-left: 45px;
    }
    ul li.odd {
        float:right;
    }
        ul li.even {
            position:relative;
        }

Comment: Do you want to float all the list-items to the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create custom bullets with css for this and then use `nth-child` selector to style them like you want as shown in below snippet.

```css
.styled-list {
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.styled-list li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.styled-list li:before {
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  top: 6px;
  left: 0;
}
.styled-list li:nth-child(even) {
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 0;
  float: right;
}
.styled-list li:nth-child(even):before {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="styled-list">
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
  <li>List Item 5</li>
  <li>List Item 6</li>
  <li>List Item 7</li>
  <li>List Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

Or you can remove `float` if you wants this:

```css
.styled-list {
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.styled-list li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.styled-list li:before {
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  top: 6px;
  left: 0;
}
.styled-list li:nth-child(even) {
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.styled-list li:nth-child(even):before {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="styled-list">
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
  <li>List Item 5</li>
  <li>List Item 6</li>
  <li>List Item 7</li>
  <li>List Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer but I need it in ZIG ZAG fashion kind of wat i made in the initial question....

Comment: @SiddharthBhatia I've added one more variant in my answer already. please check that.

Comment: This is exactly what I want.. i applied your code to mine but its still showing all the elements left align .. i there some kind of a default property that is making it do so ?